# Start/Stop application pool by name using cmd commands in c#

Tags: c#, iis, cmd

I have a cmd command to start/stop application pool in server/windows and it works:[image]

My problem is same code doesnt work in c#, code returns no error or info.
C# Code:

```
           public static string StopAppPoolCmd
           {
             get { return "cd %SYSTEMROOT%/System32/inetsrv & appcmd stop apppool /apppool.name:\"{0}\""; }
           }

           public static string StartAppPoolCmd
           {
             get { return "cd %SYSTEMROOT%/System32/inetsrv & appcmd start apppool /apppool.name:\"{0}\""; }

           }

            // Run Commands
            var cmd = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

            cmd.Start();
            /* execute "dir" */


            cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine(string.Format(start ? StartAppPoolCmd : StopAppPoolCmd, serviceName));


            //flush object
            cmd.StandardInput.Flush();
            cmd.StandardInput.Close();

            //
            // OUTPUT
            var result = Tools.CleanShellOutput(cmd.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
            Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: is the app running as the same user the command line does?

Comment: Is there anything in the event viwer ?

Comment: Why you run cmd.exe instead of appcmd.exe?

Comment: @Alex just trying on visual studio

Comment: @gencklavyeler event viewer da temiz kardeşim :)